# How can I access the joined results of lazy=’joined’, without executing a second SQL statement, or changing the parent query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Sqlalchemy lazy=’joined’ performs a join for a simple parent query, but does not seem to remember what was joined.

I have this simple one-to-one relationship defined:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    email = db.Column(db.Unicode(255), nullable=False, server_default=u'', unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, server_default='')
    ...
    userprofile = db.relationship("Userprofile",  
                                    uselist=False,
                                    backref=db.backref('userprofile', lazy='joined', innerjoin=True), 
                                    passive_deletes=True)   


class Userprofile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'userprofile'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    first_name = db.Column(db.Unicode(100), nullable=False, server_default=u'')
    last_name = db.Column(db.Unicode(100), nullable=False, server_default=u'')
    ...
    user = db.relationship("User", uselist=False, backref=db.backref('user', lazy='joined', innerjoin=True))
```

I know the userprofile relationship may have ‘too many’ options specified but I have tried everything I can think of.

As part of a 3rd party user management package, this query is executed for each web page, in order to get the user making the request, resulting in this SQL:

```
user = User.query.filter(User.id == user_id).one()

sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - SELECT  user.id AS user_id, user.email AS user_email, user.password AS user_password, userprofile_1.id AS userprofile_1_id, userprofile_1.user_id AS userprofile_1_user_id, userprofile_1.first_name AS userprofile_1_first_name, userprofile_1.last_name AS userprofile_1_last_name ...
FROM user JOIN userprofile AS userprofile_1 ON user.id = userprofile_1.user_id 
WHERE user.id = ?
```

Then, in the same view, when I want to access a field from user profile, this SQL is executed:

```
user.userprofile.first_name
  
sqlalchemy.engine.Engine - INFO - SELECT userprofile.id AS userprofile_id,  userprofile.user_id AS userprofile_user_id, userprofile.first_name AS userprofile_first_name, userprofile.last_name AS userprofile_last_name  ...
FROM userprofile 
WHERE ? = userprofile.user_id
```

Which to me is very strange.  The first query has the userprofile fields already, so why the second SQL statement?

I can’t really change the user query to add something like ‘contains_eager’ to the query, so that approach is not an option.  Also, sqlalchemy complains if I try to use lazy='dynamic' for a one-to-one relationship.

I have 2 questions then:

1. what can I do to the table definitions, if anything, to eliminate the second SQL statement?  Again, changing the User query is not an option.
2. Any idea why ‘contains_eager’ is not the default behavior for lazy=’joined’?  It seems like that should be the default.  Or is there an option in the db.relationsip function to request eager loading?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/WXBwai0e) works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the code!  Switching from backref to back_populates did the trick.  A big help, as I spent a day trying to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Gord Thompson solved it for me.

Since I posted the original code, I thought it might be helpful to post the modified code that worked.

```
class User(Base, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    email = db.Column(db.Unicode(255), nullable=False, server_default=u'', unique=True)

    userprofile = db.relationship(
        "Userprofile",
        back_populates="user",
        uselist=False,
        lazy="joined",
        innerjoin=True,
        passive_deletes=True)   

class Userprofile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'userprofile'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    first_name = db.Column(db.Unicode(100), nullable=False, server_default=u'')
    last_name = db.Column(db.Unicode(100), nullable=False, server_default=u'')

user = db.relationship("User", back_populates="userprofile", uselist=False)
```